# Gridview Row count for Specific Rows

Tags: c#, datagridview, rowcount

I have data grid view in which some rows are red and some are green now i want to get the row count for the Rows which are green colored only. How to get that

Here is how i change the color

```
for (int i = IndexNumberOfGridReceiver; i < WhatsAppCheckTotal - 1; i++)
{
    if (form1.gridReceiver.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(csvRow))
    {
        form1.gridReceiver.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        form1.gridReceiver.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
    IndexNumberOfGridReceiver = i;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet? Show some code and write what you have tried and where it fails

Comment: I am not getting what to try i tried putting if condition within row count but not working its like `RowCount[(
if gridReceiver.Rows.ForeColor =Color.Green)]`

Answer (score 0):

Where you've got stuck?

```
int greenRows = 0;
for (int i = IndexNumberOfGridReceiver; i < WhatsAppCheckTotal - 1; i++)
{
    if (form1.gridReceiver.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(csvRow))
    {
        greenRows++;
        form1.gridReceiver.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        form1.gridReceiver.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
    IndexNumberOfGridReceiver = i;
}
```

Comment: Dude i want the row count of green color row in my program this is the way i change the color of my rows

Comment: And i even dont knw this codes works or not cause need some more functions to test before testing this

Comment: Means i knw this greenRows++ but i want to know if there is any inbuilt property of DataGridView to do this

Comment: @KirteshAgrawal: why do you expect that a `DataGridView` has a property `GreenRowsCount`?

Comment: Not like that means by creating some procedure like puting if condition in rows count or anything like procedure cause i am gonna need this thing in many places so if creating procedure for it then it would be great

Comment: @KirteshAgrawal: i still don't get it why you need a "procedure". You can initialize a property or field instead of the local variable from the code above.